# Archivo utilitario django

Tags: django

tengo un proyecto Django donde requiero manejar muchos parametros como

```
url_pruebas
url_produccion
codigo_inicial
..
..
```

De momento estos parametros los defino en mi *settings.py* 
pero a medida que crece el archivo veo que son demasiados parametros
existen alguna forma donde pueda definirlos he oido algo de utils.py, pero desconosco si aplica o como usarlo, gracias por cualquier sugerencia.

Estos parametros pueden ser llamados por cualquier app de Django.

Comment: Diego, si lo consideras como parámetros de configuracuón entonces está bien que estén en el `settings.py`. Si son constantes que importas en tus aplicaciones podrías usar un archivo por cada app llamado `constants.py`, por lo menos así es cómo lo hago yo. Este archivo nuevo estaria al mismo nivel que tus `models.py`, `views.py`, etc.

Comment: gracias @César si no es pedir mucho podria agregar algun ejemplo de uso de constants.py...